# 'Access denied' while partitioning on Vista

Tags: windows-vista, partitioning

I went to Disk Management in Windows Vista and right clicked the C: drive to shrink it.

It started the process but after a long time had passed, I got an 'Access denied' error. I tried a couple of times, but always have the same result.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first run chkdsk on the partition you are trying to shrink and then try to use the disk management tool again. If that does not work, try booting [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) and shrinking the partition from there.

**Edit:** if you end up using the GParted live cd, make sure not to shrink your windows partition from the front. The front of the partition (to the left in GParted) must remain untouched in order for windows to continue to boot properly.